# $\mathcal{M}(X)$ compact in Weak* Topology

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

If $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is the space of all Borel probability measures on $X$ with Weak$^{∗}$ topology.

Is there an example where $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is compact, but $X$ is not metric or not compact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $X = \mathbb{N}$ with the "included-point topology at $0$". This topology is defined by declaring the non-empty open sets to be those containing $0$. Then $X$ is non-compact and is not Hausdorff, so is certainly not metrizable.

Since every non-empty open set in $X$ contains $0$, one can check that continuous real valued functions on $X$ are constant. In particular, the weak$^*$ topology on $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is the indiscrete topology [whose only non-empty open set is $\mathcal{M}(X)$] and hence $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is compact for the weak$^*$ topology since its only open cover is already finite.

Comment: How you conclude that, the topology in $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is the indiscrete topology?

Comment: The weak$^*$ topology is the topology which has a basis the sets of the form
$$V(\mu;f_1,\ldots,f_n;\varepsilon):=\left\{\lambda\in\mathcal M(M);\ \left|\int f_i\  \mathrm{d}\mu - \int f_i\  \mathrm{d}\lambda\right|<\varepsilon, \ \forall \ i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\right\}, $$ for continuous bounded functions $f_1, \dots, f_n$. If the $f_i$ are constant then $V(\mu;f_1,\ldots,f_n;\varepsilon) = \mathcal{M}(X)$ since the integral of a constant function against a probability measure is just that constant.